# ImportError: libpng16-57e5e0a0.so.16.37.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, linux, executable

I want to make a executable on Linux with PyInstaller and Python 3.10

My command to make a executable:

`python3 -m PyInstaller  compare_format.py`

Then I get the error message:
`Traceback (most recent call last):   File "compare_format.py", line 18, in <module>   File "/home/mark/format-compare/dist/compare_format/cv2/__init__.py", line 181, in <module>     bootstrap()   File "/home/mark/format-compare/dist/compare_format/cv2/__init__.py", line 153, in bootstrap     native_module = importlib.import_module("cv2")   File "importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module     if sys.path[0] == BASE_DIR or os.path.realpath(sys.path[0]) == BASE_DIR: ImportError: libpng16-57e5e0a0.so.16.37.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory [19027] Failed to execute script 'compare_format' due to unhandled exception!`

I expected it will make a executable for linux